# Prove that $X \ge 0 \quad \text{a.s} \iff \forall \Lambda \in \mathcal A: \mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_\Lambda X) \ge 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I found that the following result has been used extensively in my lecture note of martingale. Could you please verify if my proof is correct or contains logical mistake? Many thanks!

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be a random variable. Then $$X \ge 0 \quad \text{a.s} \iff \forall \Lambda \in \mathcal A: \mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_\Lambda X) \ge 0$$

My attempt:

$\Longrightarrow$ Because $X \ge 0$ a.s, $\mathbf{1}_\Lambda X \ge 0$ a.s. The claim then follows.

$\Longleftarrow$ Assume the contrary that there exists $\Lambda \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (\Lambda) >0$ and $X(\omega) <0$ for all $\omega \in \Lambda$. Then $\mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_\Lambda X) = \int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_\Lambda X \, d \mu  <0$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only gap is the proof of last strict inequality: $\mu(\Lambda)>0$ and $X(\omega)<0$ for all $\omega \in \Lambda$ implies $\mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_\Lambda X) = \int_\Lambda X \, d \mu  <0$.

If you will prove it rigorously, you need in smth like that:  let $\mu(\Lambda)>0$, then there exists $n$ such that the set $\Lambda_n=\{\omega: X(\omega)\leq -\frac1n\}$ has $\mu(\Lambda_n)>0$, then 
$$
\mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_{\Lambda_n} X) = \int_{\Lambda_n} X \, d \mu \leq \int_{\Lambda_n} -\frac1n \, d \mu = -\frac{\mu(\Lambda_n)}n <0
$$
which is impossible. So we get contradiction with assumption...

I prefer here the direct proof to the proof from the contrary. Prove that for $\Lambda=\{\omega:X(\omega)<0\}$ we have $\mu(\Lambda)=0$.

Define $\Lambda_n = \{\omega: X(\omega)\leq -\frac1n\}$. Then 
$$
0\leq \mathbb E (\mathbf{1}_{\Lambda_n} X) = \int_{\Lambda_n} X \, d \mu \leq \int_{\Lambda_n} -\frac1n \, d \mu = -\frac{\mu(\Lambda_n)}n\leq 0
$$
which follows $\mu(\Lambda_n)=0$ for all $n$.

Take $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda_n=\Lambda=\{\omega: X(\omega)<0\}$. Note that $\Lambda_n\subset \Lambda_{n+1}$, so continuity from below of measure $\mu$ gives that 
$$
\mu(\Lambda) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(\Lambda_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0.
$$